# How to change IP address pool in DHCP scope without affecting existing leased IPs

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

Within the DHCP, we have the following IP available for distribution

Start IP Address
10.1.23.15
End IP Address
10.1.23.199

The current utilization of the IPs is around 50%
We are looking to shrink the starting IP Address to 10.1.23.25 for handing out static IP for a bunch of new hardware. Does anyone know what happens to be existing leased IPs when we make such change?

- Does the lease renew upon the change, or when the lease expires at the default 8 days?
- We want to avoid user seeing any disconnection or glitches after the
  change

I couldn't find documentation on what to expect upon making the above change. Does any experienced AD admins has any input on how we can accomplish this change silently to prevent impacts to our users?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change won't have any immediate effect on any running DHCP clients. When the DHCP clients reboot they'll send a request asking to continue using their currently leased ip address and will be denied and will then request a new ip address. The same process should occur when running clients attempt to renew their currently leased ip address. Make sure that you don't assign any of the ip addresses that you're removing from the pool to any other hosts until they've been released from the existing DHCP clients.